# How to get the completed task on Executor Service till some time?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to retrieve the results for the threads that have completed their task and retrieve the result and ignore other threads. My aim is to do something like this.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
            service.submit(threadClass);
            // some thread that generates result in 5 seconds say
        }
        
        // Main thread does some work here that takes time


        /*
        The task that has finished till this point should be taken
        Let's say 7 results are generated till this point,
        So get the 7 results and stop other threads
        Want result like a List<Integer>
        */

        

        service.shutdownNow(); // stop all other threads
          

    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to use [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutorService.submit` returns a `Future` that can be used to wait for completion and `get` the result.

There is a version of `get` that has a timeout, this is useful for polling for completion.

You should collect the Futures and use them. Keep an array of 100 Futures, then when required, loop over them collecting results until you have enough results for your needs.

Comment: get() Retrieves the result of a task, waiting endlessly if it is not yet
available, also using the timeOut version of get here may affect the result expected , you should test for the status of the Future before calling get(), you can use isDone() method to do that.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't really change the gist of the answer, which is: submit returns a Future - use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html), a blocking queue is used internally, and the "completed" `Future` will be put into this queue, so you can call `queue#poll` to get all finish `Future`.
:

```
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
        CompletionService<Integer> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(service);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
            completionService.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call() throws Exception {
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int nextInt = random.nextInt(10000);
                    System.out.println("I will take " + nextInt + " ms to finish");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(nextInt);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("I am interrupt");
                        return -1;
                    }
                    System.out.println("I am finish");
                    return nextInt;
                }
            });
        }
        // do other work
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        List<Integer> completeResult = new ArrayList<>();
        Future<Integer> future;
        while ((future = completionService.poll()) != null) {
            try {
                completeResult.add(future.get());
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                // exception
            }
        }
        service.shutdownNow();
        System.out.println(completeResult);
```